# Pass array value to colspan to create column table in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am having a problem to pass a value from array to colspan, so I can have    dynamic multi column.

```
$my_values = array();
while ($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
   $my_values[] = $value;
 }
}
print_r($my_values);
```

and this is the output the I got for printing the $my_values:

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 2 [2] => 1 )
```

What I am trying to do here is creating table and pass those array to colspan:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM assignments WHERE course_id=1";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) != 0) {
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
          echo '<th colspan="'.$my_values['0'].'">'.$row['assignment_name'].'</th>';
        }
      }
```

where is `$my_values['0']` will get just 3. what I am trying to do here is I want to get index 0 first, then index 2 then index 3. so the first one can create 3 columns and the second one 2 columns and the third 1 columns.

can you help me guys with this issue?

Comment: make use of a variable and increment it on every loop ?

Comment: use an increment variable or use foreach to handle those things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code. it may help you with

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM assignments WHERE course_id=1";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) != 0) {
            $i = 0; //-------------->INITIALIZE THE VARIABLE
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
          echo '<th colspan="'.$my_values[$i].'">'.$row['assignment_name'].'</th>';
          $i++; //----------------> INCREMENT THE VARIABLE
        }
      }
```

Comment: keep rocking bro... If you have any doubt just post it. We are happy to help you out...